# Ubuntu 22.04 Samba Server / User Cant login / windows pc cant access

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

First of all, sorry for my poor English.

I have few questions for Samba on Ubuntu

I just new noob in Linux system, my new company wanted me to upgrade our service team file server from Debian Bullseye samba to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I have try install and setup the setting in Debian as practice lot of time to setup a Samba server in Debian Bullseye and as well in Linux mint cinnamon and the Samba in Debian & Linux Mint working fine and can be access on Windows XP,7,10,11 machine & Linux machine.

but with the same setting I try to install and setup the Samba on New PC with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS the service running but fail to access by other user (even in the Ubuntu machine it self on the network folder I cant access the share file)

now the problem I facing:

1. same as I work on Debian machine, I have add user by using command as below that I found online:

**@sudo useradd --system --no-create-home -s /bin/false username**

(full command from web is @sudo useradd --system --no-create-home --group "groupname" -s /bin/false "username" / but due to we have just few workers and only for us to store our personal work file so I have take away the **group** command so we no need to manage group and just concentrate on user alone is fine, and I have tested this command on Debian & Linux Mint, is working fine)

2. I also has add user in smbpasswd by command below:

**@sudo smbpasswd -a username**

and enable the user with:

**@sudo smbpasswd -e username**

3. I also has enable public to all user read write and execute with command so all have full control on the folder, but then been limit access by using samba user control and access.

**@sudo chmod ugo+rwx /home/charles/share/username**

4. I have update the system and install the samba service and again update the system.

then I have try to setup the Samba smb.confi and restart the samba servie and let it run.

as all the work I follow the step I work on Debian Samba server that is working perfectly, but on Ubuntu, it start to fail.

Fail Problem:

A. as all the setting as same as in Debian, that I have tested working fine, but in Ubuntu the share file can been access by the added user, I have try to log in the file on the same Ubuntu Samba server by clicking on the network icon and log in on the pc it self with the user that I have been added example user john that i have added with the useradd command, it fail to log in.

- all the after added user example:John, Jenny, Sally, Puki cant login to access theirs folder that usually working fine with Debian Samba server, but in Ubuntu it fail to work.
- on the Ubuntu PC it self, in the network icon login only the main user "charles: that is created during the format main user can access all the folder (charles is my account, as administrator I have access to all user folder in case any problem I can help to backup for other user) but other then that all other user add after installation is not working.

B. I suspected is Useradd problem, so I try clean format the Ubuntu and reset all to clean and re-setup all user by only using:

**@sudo useradd username - to fully add user**

**@sudo passwd username - to set password**

**@sudo smbpasswd -a username - to set samba password**

**@sudo smbpasswd -e username - to enable**

and log in the user one by one to the Ubuntu PC and confirm all is working fine and retest the samba service, also is the same, cant been access by other user, only the charles main admin account can access to the folder.

C. I have tested to log in the folder on other machine on the network worse happen. all the Windows base PC XP, 7, 8, 10, 11 cant access the folder, I can saw the folder but the time click on it, it request to log in, (ok this is correct, need user log in for access that is what I want, all working fine on Debian, but still same fail on Ubuntu Samba server) I try to log in with the user one by one, all cant access, worse is the main admin account also cant access to folder in Windows machine. I also try on Linux machine, (debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint) all other user also cant log in, but thanks god in Linux machine, the admin account still manage to log in. only windows machine all is not working for samba running in Ubuntu.

I have try to check from the web, for test to by pass firewall in windows, I also have try to total disable firewall, and also disable the antivirus, also has follow the instructions to modify the registry, also try to re-setup, and set allow insecure guest auth at registry and also have try set the windows user and password same as samba server also cant access, and also try set the samba server password and user same as windows user also same, cant access,

I also saw that Ubuntu user has actual user to access samba, I also try to ask our domain admin create a test domain and all the Ubuntu in it, and few windows PC and linux pc in it, all have actual account, and actual user that is running fine, but still the same, cant access the folder.

**below is the actual samba configurations that I use, working fine in Debian, but have problem in Ubuntu**

**smb.conf**

**

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 
#======================= Global Settings =======================
## Browsing/Identification ###
# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
#### Networking ####
# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes
#### Debugging/Accounting ####
# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000
# We want Samba to only log to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd}.
# Append syslog@1 if you want important messages to be sent to syslog too.
   logging = file
# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
####### Authentication #######
# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone server" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes
# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes
# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
########## Domains ###########
#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = classic
# primary domain controller', 'server role = classic backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#
# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile
# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U
# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd
# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
############ Misc ############
# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash
# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.
# Maximum number of usershare. 0 means that usershare is disabled.
#   usershare max shares = 100
# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = no
#======================= Share Definitions =======================
# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no
# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes
# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700
# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700
# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S
# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes
# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = no
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = no
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
##################################################
[global]
    server string = Samba Server
    workgroup = SERVICETEAM
    netbios name = FILESERVER
    security = user
    map to guest = Bad User
    name resolve order = bcast host
#   include = /etc/samba/smbshare.conf
# Dont remove the "include" line, for record and future use
##################################################
[Chalres]
    path = /home/charles/share/charles
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    valid users = charles
    force users = charles
    create mask = 0640
    directory mask = 0750
[Christine]
    path = /home/charles/share/christine
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    valid users = christine
    force users = christine
    create mask = 0640
    directory mask = 0750
[Cindy]
    path = /home/charles/share/cindy
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    valid users = cindy
    force users = cindy
    create mask = 0640
    directory mask = 0750
[Jenny]
    path = /home/charles/share/jenny
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    valid users = jenny
    force users = jenny
    create mask = 0640
    directory mask = 0750
[Joan]
    path = /home/charles/share/joan
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    valid users = joan
    force users = joan
    create mask = 0640
    directory mask = 0750
[Puki]
    path = /home/charles/share/puki
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    valid users = puki
    force users = puki
    create mask = 0640
    directory mask = 0750
[Public]
    path = /home/charles/share/public
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    writeable = yes
    valid users = charles, christine, cindy jenny, joan, puki
    force users = charles, christine, cindy jenny, joan, puki
    create mask = 0645
    directory mask = 0755
```

**

**I have run out of options, and also run out of idea, what I want is very simple, I just want to share the folder out from Ubuntu running the Samba I just want it same as the old Debian Bullseye system sharing by samba and can be access by Windows & Linux System on the network, and limit access right of users only can access on their own folder or public share folder, please all the pro, help me on this so I could setup the system and keep the system running.
Thanks On Advance**

Comment: Why are you downgrading from Bullseye to Ubuntu 22.04 ? Why is your company still using XP and Windows 7 ? Why is your smb.conf such a mess ?

Comment: @Rowland Penny 1. you need to understand that some of the old machine and tester that still in use, the controller system only support in windows XP and Windows 7. (PS: some our department have Win 98 & win 95 and also OS2) 2. I still noob and and still learning, please show me what is the setting that is nice and clean and still can limit only 1 user access the folder but other user cant access. 3. sorry I didnt know how you categorize it, how could a Bullseye to Ubuntu 22.04 is a downgrade? security, updated software, and support, Ubuntu has all latest version compare to Bullseye.

Comment: My first thoughts were 'go and find another job', your network is ancient, some of it relies on SMBv1 and others rely on (shudder) Lanman auth. If you are going to stay, then I suggest you plan to upgrade everything, Samba has shut down lanman auth and is working on removing SMBv1. At one time Ubuntu was a very good distro, but is steadily (in my opinion) going down the pan. If you require the latest Samba for Bullseye, I can point you at a very good repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Debian creates a home directory with permissions of 755.

This allows the owner full access and to everyone else it allows them the ability to traverse ( open ) the folder to see what's inside.

Starting with Ubuntu 22.04 the default permissions on home directories changed to 750. The owner of the folder is the only one that can access or even traverse the folder.

The problem with a path like this: `/home/charles/share/username` is charles.

You need to allow samba access to the entire path to the shared resource:

Change it back to the old Ubuntu defaults:

```
chmod o+rx /home/charles
```

Or even just set the folder to be traversable by others:

```
chmod o+x /home/charles
```

Comment: thanks you very much, it working perfectly on my machine now. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me after upgrade to 22.04 from 20. After I was unable to access my network shared locactions from a windows11 etc. I realized the shares was not in the smb.conf file. When I added them there, they worked again.

the shares as they are in the description above (conf file) are valid. I use whole drives as shares instead of folders so my pahts are /mnt/DRIVExxxname/folder

I restarted the sambashare and everything was fine

Comment: You upgraded from Ubuntu Core to 22.04? Only Ubuntu Core uses the one digit version number.